# What resources exist to teach me how to use web services in Java?

Tags: java, web-services

I'd like to learn to use web services in java, but I can't figure out how to get started.

Are there any websites which could teach me these concepts, particularly those which include example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, I would recommend you getting and at least scanning through [JSR-224](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224) (Java API for XML-Based Web Services), which is de facto API for building Web Services in Java. It is very technical document, but might help you understanding on how to use one or another feature of Java Web Services. As it comes to implementation, you have a choice of multiple frameworks. One of them - Apache CXF - is mentioned in other comments along with links to the tutorials.

Comment: That would be kind of heavy-reading for the OP since he claims to be a beginner at these things. The best route IMO would be to play around with a few frameworks out there, see the result of those experiments and then try to dig deep rather than getting started with a dry technical document. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this [JAX-WS hello world example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) to understand the basic of how web service works in Java.

Comment: gud to see you here mkyong